# How many products are possible when chlorination of cyclohexane takes place?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Since each atom is identical and equally likely to get attacked in cyclohexane therefore according to me only one product will be formed.Our sir made us write this answer
[image]

Comment: Mono chlorination?

Comment: Yes monochlorination

Comment: Should be one only, where did you get the question from.

Comment: Polychlorination will give more than three products, even if we limit "poly" to 2.

Comment: Exactly how many products and what will be their structure?

Comment: I count seven .

Comment: This question is honestly very vague, and lacks lots of details. "Our sir hasnt specified" isn't a valid excuse for a poorly framed question, and neither can we help you with understanding your teacher's intent. I'd advise you to carefully decide what is the concept that's bothering you, and not consider it a "homework" that you're giving us.

Answer (score 1):

For cyclohexane, you're correct that since all carbon atoms are exactly the same, only one monochloro derivative exists.

The answer could be 2 if we did the monochlorination of cyclohex**e**ne instead.

Allowing dichlorination gives more than just three products - due to both geometrical and optical isomerism.

Therefore, to obtain the answer 3, the reactant ring must be different. Currently, as it stands, the answer 3 is wrong.