# Monochlorination of (R)-2-chlorohexane: Number of possible chiral dichloro products

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-structure, radicals

> How many possible chiral dichloro products can be formed when (R)-2-chlorohexane reacted with one equivelent of $\ce{Cl2}$ in the presence of UV radiation (monochlorination only)?
> $$\ce{C6H11Cl + Cl2 ->[$h\nu$] C6H10Cl2 + HCl}$$

I am getting 8 as the answer but given answer is 9:

- (2*R*)-1,2-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,3*R*)-2,3-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,3*S*)-2,3-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,4*R*)-2,4-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,4*S*)-2,4-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,5*R*)-2,5-dichlorohexane
- (2*R*,5*S*)-2,5-dichlorohexane
- (5*R*)-1,5-dichlorohexane

Am I missing something? Will the stereochemistry of the already chlorinated C change during the reaction?

Comment: Don't put your whole question in the title.

Comment: There are nine total dichloro products. Seven are chiral. the eighth does not have a chirality center. The ninth is a meso compound.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/93766/how-many-products-are-possible-when-chlorination-of-cyclohexane-takes-place ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/153943/possibility-of-further-chlorination-of-hexachlorocyclohexane